# Typescript generic functions not working as expected - parameter containing another generic type than required, compiles OK

Tags: generics, typescript

I am trying to develop simple event bus class in Typescript, where it will be possible to publish events and subscribe to them. 
It will be nice to have binding between published topic and the interface of data published. I have tried to achieve this using function and class generics, however some of my test cases are not working as expected (in a way that the lines I would expect to fail are compiled OK). I have also added example from: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html
, which works as expected. In real-world situation I am planning to have instances of topics stored somewhere as singletons.

```
interface BaseMessage { };
interface MyMessage extends BaseMessage {
    a: number;
};
interface MyMessage2 extends BaseMessage {
    b: string;
}
class Topic<A> {}
class MyTopic extends Topic<MyMessage> { };
class MyTopic2 extends Topic<MyMessage2> { };
class MyTopic3 extends Topic<MyMessage2> { }; // example of another topic using the same message interface

class EventBus {
    publish<T extends BaseMessage> (topic: Topic<T>, data: T): void {}
    subscribe<T extends BaseMessage>(topic: Topic<T>, callback: (arg?: T) => void): void  { }
    loggingIdentity<T>(arg: Array<T>): Array<T> {
        return arg;
    }
    loggingIdentity2<T>(arg: Topic<T>): Topic<T> {
        return arg;
    }
}
class Test {
    init(): void {
        let eb = new EventBus();
        eb.loggingIdentity<MyMessage2>(new Array<MyMessage2>()); // works just fine
        eb.loggingIdentity<MyMessage2>(new Array<MyMessage>()); // error as expected
        eb.loggingIdentity2<MyMessage2>(new Topic<MyMessage2>()); // works just fine
        eb.loggingIdentity2<MyMessage2>(new Topic<MyMessage>()); // I am expecting this to fail, but this works
        eb.publish<MyMessage2>(new MyTopic2(), { a: 1 }); // fails on not satisfying data parameter interface - expected
        eb.publish<MyMessage2>(new MyTopic2(), { b: "hello" }); // works just fine
        eb.publish<MyMessage2>(new MyTopic(), { b: "hello" }); // I am expecting this to fail, because of the first parameter, but it works
    }
}
```

Maybe I am missing something there. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
class Topic<A> {}
```

The class `Topic` doesn't use the generic type `A`. So, `Topic<SomethingHere>` and `Topic<SomethingElse>` are compatible.

Use the generic type `A` and the errors will occur as expected:

```
class Topic<A> { abc: A; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, it is sufficient to update class Topic this way: class Topic<A extends BaseMessage> {private member: A}